# Want to validate the part of a string shouldn't be null

Tags: cypress

I have this following element which contain a string for `Practitioner`, its value is `1- zzz`. How to validate after `-` it shouldn't be `null`. Even if there is a string or empty. It shouldn't print `null`. Also want to select the value under `Practitioner` (currently hard coded the position of the element as `2`)

```
<div class="styles__container___BfTYi">
<div class="styles__subHeader___18Yg1">Practitioner</div>
<div class="styles__data___1senX">1- zzz</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have the following code to retrieve the text,

```
 cy.get(pageSelector.practitionerValidator).eq(2).then(function($getText) {
        let practitionerName = $getText.text();
        var validateLastName = practitionerName.split(' ');
        cy.log(validateLastName[1]);
        expect(validateLastName[1]).to.not.equal('null');
    })
```

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as "part of a string". The *whole* string is either null or not null, but not half of it. If the string was built concatenating other smaller strings (very likely from your examples) you need to validate each part **before** concatenation.

Comment: Add the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check that the entire string is not `null` like this:

```js
cy.get('.styles__data___1senX').then(($ele) => {
  expect($ele.text()).to.not.be.null
})
```

Or if you want to check that your inner text is not empty you can do:

```js
cy.get('.styles__data___1senX').then(($ele) => {
  expect($ele.text()).to.not.be.empty
})
```

You can find the selector from the text `Practitioner` like this:

```js
cy.contains('Practitioner')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('div[class*="styles__data__"]').then(($ele) => {
      expect($ele.text()).to.not.be.null
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you alpan, I get it but I am not confident on the locator. Can we find an relative one.

Comment: You can use a locator that works for you. This is just an example. Updated my answer, yoou can check.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate the level of detail you gave.

I will be going off this assumption.

- the `Practitioner` string will be random can spaces or no spaces after the `-` (ie `34- sdfwe`, `3-`   , `1-` )

I would use a regex to check the format of the string to check the string starts with a digit followed by a dash and a space with either a string, spaces, or nothing. `/\d+\-\s(\w+|\s+)?/`

Your code would look a bit like this.

```js
cy.get(pageSelector.practitionerValidator)
  .eq(2)
  .invoke('text') // get text
  .should('match', /\d+\-\s(\w+|\s+)?/) // use regex assertion
```